# jQuery if statment with hover, How to get this working

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Can someone help me with this? When the document loads it automatically does the alert. Not when class b1 or b2 is hovered. How do I fix it to make it when b1 or b2 is hovered to then do the alert?

I am sure it has to do with the document.ready function, but I thought it would not alert till the if statement of hover is initiated. So how do I make it work? Thanks!

```
function hoverHere(){
    if($('.b1').hover()){
        alert('Hello World');
    };
    if($('.b2').hover()){
        alert('Hello World');
    };
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    hoverHere();
})
```

HTML

```
<section class="headings">
    <div class="b1">content</div>
    <div class="b2">content</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You need to *bind* a mouseover or mouseenter event. Also, `alert` is a **horrible** choice to use in any mouse events that are not clicks.

Comment: I strongly recommend to have [this API](http://api.jquery.com/) as bookmark. If you check for the `hover()` documentation, you would have noticed that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Obviously I am doing it wrong. I will replace the alert with different code. I just am trying to get it working. @ThiefMaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you wanted to do something different for each hover:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.b1').hover(function() {
        alert("Hello world ! - b1");
    }); 
    $('.b2').hover(function() {
        alert("Hello world ! - b2");
    }); 
});
```

Another way you could do it is:

```
function hoverHere(){
    $('.b1').hover(function() {
        alert("Hello world ! - b1");
    });
    $('.b2').hover(function() {
        alert("Hello world ! - b2");
    });
}

$(document).ready(hoverHere);
```

Comment: Thank you. I do want to do something different with each hover. This will work great!

Answer (score 3):

Simply :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.b1, .b2').hover(function() {
        alert("Hello world !");
    }); 
})
```